# Where is variables located in Wordpress like how it works for e.g (have_rows('help_list'))

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 <div id="how_can_we_help">
  <div class="wehelp_wrappper">
   <div class="page_container">
    <div class="help_title_info">
     <?php the_field('help_title');?>
    </div>
   
    <div class="wehelp_wrap">
     <?php if( have_rows('help_list') ): ?>
     <?php while( have_rows('help_list') ): the_row(); ?>
     <!---->
     <div class="wehelp_box">
      <div class="wehelp_icon"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('icon');?>"  alt="icon"/></div>
       <div class="wehelp_shortinfo">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link');?>"><?php the_sub_field('title');?></a></h4>
         <p><?php the_sub_field('info');?></p>
       </div>
       <div class="gohelp_details"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link');?>">Discover More</a> 
       </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I am new to wordpress, I just trying to figure out where this "help_list" is located in our wordpress site. also there is a while loop on this "help_list" but no idea where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website has ACF plugin installed.

and it comes from the **Repeater Field** of the ACF plugin.

Check here for more :

1. [Check this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)
2. [More link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/)

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin for WordPress brings that for you.
you can check more information about this in link :

[ACF - have_rows](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/)